How to find corresponding node in a comfyUI custom node?
I'm trying to write a comfyUI custom node, when dealing with the frontend part, in the callback async nodeCreated(node), console.log(node.id) just print -1. Or to avoid XYZ problem, how am I supposed to change the properties of node so I can show extra text on node? Currently I try to record the id <--> properties mapping in nodeCreated callback, and draw the text in the onDrawForeground callback if the id is right.

Okay I just discovered that the id is actually set afterwards, so I can record the id in later callback.
Full code is here:
import { app } from "../../scripts/app.js";
import { api } from "../../scripts/api.js";
const propertiesMapping = {};
const nodes = [];
app.registerExtension({
  name: "ShowLastTextEx",
  async beforeRegisterNodeDef(nodeType, nodeData, app) {
    if (nodeData.python_module !== "custom_nodes.RememberingUtils") return;
    console.log(this, arguments)
    nodeType.prototype.onGetInputs = function() {
      this.label = "label changed"
      console.log(this, arguments)
    }
    nodeType.prototype.onDrawForeground = function(ctx, graphcanvas) {
      if (this.flags.collapsed) return;
      if (!this.properties.text) return;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillColor = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,this.size[1]);
      ctx.font = "48px serif";
      ctx.fillText(this.properties.text, 60, 80);
      ctx.restore();
    }
    api.addEventListener('RememberingUtils:change', function(data) {
      console.log('change', data, this);
      const id = data.detail.node;
      const properties = propertiesMapping[id];
      properties.text = id;
    });
  },
  async nodeCreated(node) {
    nodes.push(node);
  },
  async setup() {
    console.log('setup', arguments, nodes.map(x => x.id));
    nodes.forEach(({id, properties}) => {
      propertiesMapping[id] = properties;
    });
  },
});


Note that you should also record id <--> properties mapping in the onAdded callback, to deal with ad-hoc altering of the graph. See also https://github.com/jagenjo/litegraph.js/tree/master/guides
